# Linked Server: Unable to connect to server after patch

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, linked-server

#### Problem statement

Server A ( SQL Server 2012 base version ) was able to connect via linked server to Server B (SQL Server 2012 SP2 11.0.5058.0 version)

Server A was then updated to SP4 (11.0.7001.0) version and now unable to establish connection via linked server to server B

#### Error message

TCP Provider: An Existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "XXX" returned message "Client unable to establish connection."( Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10054)

I believe the root cause to this is the TLS configuration https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe

But how do I fix it?

#### Additional Info

Server A has OS patching done recently but when comparing the patches on both servers, they have the same ones installed. Patches in Server B were installed earlier than Server A

I don't see any error message in SQL Server's error log. I get the error message when I try to test the connection to Server B from Server A and vice versa.

Server A can connect 2 other servers that are SQL Server 2017

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5qct.png)

left - Server A

right - Server B

Comment: Start by updating everything to the latest SQL Server 2012 SP4 patch, then think about upgrading to a version that is still in support

Comment: Unfortunately since Server B is a Prod server, the application team wants me to find the root cause of the connection issue first before proceeding with patch, citing concern that this might disrupt other servers Server B is connected to.

Comment: Looks like you've found the issue: TLS problems. The solution is to patch. Does the team not have test servers to use? And surely they should be keeping their patching up to date anyway.

Comment: Presumably your OS patching - and registry changes, no doubt - have affected the SSL/TLS protocols available for both incoming and outgoing connections. Have you examined the registry settings below HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\ to see which Client and Server protocols have `DisabledByDefault` and `Enabled` settings?

Comment: @charlieface Server A is the test server. They are not keeping it updated for now as they are planning to move the app onto a SQL 2017 Server eventually

Comment: @alwaysLearning pic updated. Im thinking since Server A has more than Server B...surely there must be a way to use the old config from Server A to join to Server B?

Comment: That picture doesn't tell us anything except that someone has applied some registry settings to Server A - but not exactly what they are. Go back to the KB3135244 link in your question and search for the discussion about the `DisabledByDefault` and `Enabled` registry values. It seems that some/all of those may be applied to the SSL3.0, TLS1.0, TLS1.1 and TLS1.2 protocols on Server A.